# gcc vectorization messages

Tags: gcc

I read (http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-writing-cc-code-in-vector-format/) that the Intel compiler has a flag to output information about vectorization - things like "BLOCK WAS VECTORIZED.", etc. Does gcc have anything similar? I am just trying see if I can get an idea of what is getting vectorized and what is not. For example, I'd like to make a demo like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Point3
{
public:
  Point3() : Components(3)
  {
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = 0;
  }

  const unsigned int Components;
  float data[3];

private:


};

class Point4
{
public:
  Point4() : Components(4)
  {
    data[0] = 0;
    data[1] = 0;
    data[2] = 0;
    data[3] = 0;
  }

  const unsigned int Components;

  float data[4];
private:


};

template <typename T>
static float Add(const T& a, const T& b)
{
  float sumValues = 0.0f;
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < a.Components; ++i)
  {
    sumValues += a.data[i] + b.data[i];
  }
  return sumValues;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Point3> point3vec(1000);
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < point3vec.size() - 1; ++i)
  {
    Add(point3vec[i], point3vec[i+1]);
  }

  std::vector<Point4> point4vec(1000);
  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < point4vec.size(); ++i)
  {
    Add(point4vec[i], point4vec[i+1]);
  }

}
```

and see if one of the loops gets vectorized while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=n` at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-ftree_002dvectorizer_002dverbose-690

In newer versions of GCC use `-fopt-info-vec -fopt-info-vec-missed`.

Comment: Cool, that's what I was looking for. I'm assuming the default is n=0?

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised the docs don't explicitly say so, but yes, I assume so, since you get no output unless using that option explicitly.

Comment: I compiled the (edited) code above with -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=8. I get: 60: note: not vectorized: inner-loop count not invariant. line 54: note: not vectorized: inner-loop count not invariant.
line 44: note: not vectorized: unsupported data-type. Can you suggest better code to demonstrate vectorization? Is the problem that my classes also contain the Components member, making the entire class data no longer a multiple of 4 floats in size?
Or it also sounds like the loop going to point3vec.size() is not allowing vectorization because it is not a constant?

Comment: I'll start a different thread for this and accept your answer here.